# Cannot enable Azure AD Domain Services

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id

I try to enable "Domain Services" in azure. The azure ad comes from an office 365 tenant. The problem is I don't even see the option to enable domain services (I looked under Active Directory -> Configure).

Do I have to activate it somewhere because it's in a preview state? I have another tenant and there it's no problem to enable Domain Services.

Thanks for the information.

Thomas